# If $S_{t}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{t}W_{i}$, is it true: $\sigma(S_{1},...,S_{n})=\sigma(W_{1},...,W_{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

If $S_{t}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{t}W_{i}$, is it true: $\sigma(S_{1},...,S_{n})=\sigma(W_{1},...,W_{n})$ where the random variables are real-valued.

I assume in general this is incorrect. What are weaker - less general conditions - to render this correct?

Does "addition" operate any differently? I.e. is it also true that

$T_{t}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}V_{i}$ implies: $\sigma(T_{1},...,T_{n})=\sigma(V_{1},...,V_{n})$?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you always have $$\sigma(S_1,\dots,S_n) \subseteq \sigma(W_1,\dots,W_n).$$
The converse is not true in general. For example, let $n=2$ and $W_1 \equiv 0$ and $W_2 \sim N(0,1)$. Then $S \equiv 0$ and hence 
$$\{\emptyset,\Omega\} = \sigma(S_1,S_2) \subsetneq \sigma(W_1,W_2) = \sigma(W_2).$$
The claim is true if you require that $W_t \neq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$, because then $S_t \neq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$ and we have $$ \frac{S_{t}}{S_{t-1}} = W_t$$
so $\sigma(W_1,\dots,W_n) \subseteq \sigma(S_1,\dots,S_n)$.

In the additive case, the claim is always true because we can always write $$ T_t - T_{t-1} = V_t.$$

Comment: simple and to the point, thanks!